# How to make dynamic routing system?

Tags: php, url, routes

I'm just trying to create a dynamic routing system or something like that.

this is i have done so far,

this is my `.htaccess` file to serve all routes to index.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

my `index.php` file.

```
<?php 

//get request url
$url = rawurldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

//match the request url with above urls. 
//do i have to match the above URL with these each urls??
$array = array(
                'category' => array('hello','category1','category2'),
                'page' => array('page1','page2','page3'),
            );
 //here i am using array, but the URL can also come from database.
$flag = 0;
foreach($array as $key=>$arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $ar)
    {

        if(preg_match('/'.$ar.'/', $url) && $key == 'category'){
            include('category.php');
            $flag =1;
            exit;
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/'.$ar.'/', $url) && $key == 'page') {
            include('page.php');
            $flag =1;
            exit;
        }

    }


}
if($flag ==0)
{
    include('404.php');
}
```

here what i am doing is, if my route match, i am sending the control to separate files, that will generate the HTML or some code..

The Problem here i am facing is do i have to match each of the Request URL with my saved URL or there will some other solution for this, because if someone has around 10,000 URLS in the database or in the array, this will take so long in comparison,

please provide a solution or correct me if i am doing it wrong way.

Comment: Having an array named `$array` does not seem like a good idea, consider naming it to something more clear.

Comment: There may be several ways to do this better, however as a side note, 10s of thousands of routes is unlikely to be good solution. You could, for example, store and index the category-page tree in database in a way that you can fetch page by URL and cache the results in memory so it builds up over time. But this whole thing seems very basic procedural style programming. Why not consider a modern a framework instead of trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Script47 yes, i know $array var name is not relevant, i just used it for testing.

Comment: @marekful can you explain a little bit of by PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this sort of system makes use of `$_GET`. So you'd have a folder called `modules` and within that you'd have all your pages.

So,

```
modules -> index    -> index.php
modules -> home     -> home.php
modules -> sign-in  -> sign-in.php
modules -> sign-out -> sign-out.php
modules -> 404      -> 404.php
```

Then your links would look something like the following respectively:

```
<a href="?action=sign-out">Sign Out</a>
```

Then you capture the `$_GET['action']` on each request and use [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) and or [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) to check the modules directory to see if said module in `$_GET['action']` exists, if it does then you can load it in, otherwise you can load the 404 or the module you'd like to show in place of the error page.

Doing it like this saves you the trouble of having to define all your pages in an array.

Comment: i guessed this example from wp category URL structure, but i still didnt get this, how would you handle if you have 1000 URL that will serve by multiple files, like 3 or 4 different files.